# Arrow function in typescript interface with return type as void

Tags: angular, typescript, arrow-functions

I am trying to write arrow function in my type Script interface as below but getting error **"Class 'ToastrService' incorrectly implements interface 'IToastr'."**

```
interface IToastr{
    (message:string,title:string):void;
}

@Injectable()
export class ToastrService implements IToastr {
    (message:string,title:string):void {
         toastr.success(message,title);
    }
}
```

My question is:  can we define a function signature in TS interface with return type as void??

I did try searching google as well but did not find any example. Thanks !!

Comment: Why don't you define it as a regular method?

Comment: I defined earlier as regular method and it work as well. But just thought of replacing regular function with arrow function and I was surprised that it is not that regular practice. My question is, why we can not do this ?? if we cannot.

Comment: I'm not a TypeScript expert, but I'm not even sure of what you're trying to achieve here. What is the interface used for? How do you intend to inject this service and invoke this function? I'm not sure it's even possible to be a clas and a function at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Please consult the official typescript for more info.

**Example 1:**

```
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): void;
}
let mySearch: SearchFunc;
mySearch = function(source: string, subString: string) {
    // do smth
}
```

**Example 2: Solution: You should name your function**

```
interface IToastr{
    FuncName(message:string,title:string):void;
}

class ToastrService implements IToastr {
    FuncName(message:string,title:string):void {
         // toastr.success(message,title);
    }
}
```

Comment: after doing some research, I think, it make sense to have a named function in the interface. As arrow functions are anonymous functions so any class/service implementing that function would be useless for the class/service consumer as it has no name. Although thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing seems fine just missing a name for the function (or if this is a constructor then the `constructor` keyword is missing)

```
interface IToastr{
    toast(message:string,title:string):void;
}

@Injectable()
export class ToastrService implements IToastr {
    toast(message:string,title:string):void {
         toastr.success(message,title);
    }
}
```

Comment: after doing some research, I think, it make sense to have a named function in the interface. As arrow functions are anonymous functions so any class/service implementing that function would be useless for the class/service consumer as it has no name. Although thanks for your response.